# How would you define the relation between (for example) "Italian" and "languages"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm building a web site where I have a list of topics, and I need to denote the relation between them. e.g.:

Topic: Italian.
Ancestors: Languages -> European
Predecessors: Verbs, Nouns...

Another example may be:

Topic: Internet Explorer.
Ancestors: Software -> Browsers
Predecessors: Menus, Add-Ons, keyboard-shortcuts...

And so on.

The problem is that I'm not sure "Ancestors" and "predecessors" are suitable.

Other options I had in mind are subtopics/supertopics, and children/parents.

What do you think? Which way articulates the meaning best?

Comment: _Predecessor_ would mean "that has been followed or replaced by another".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment and the edit kiamlaluno. We use these terms in computer science to denote a relation I thought was similar, but maybe I got it wrong..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about ***category*** and ***subcategory***?

Comment: +1 Agreed; I can't see anyone struggling with this terminology.

Comment: My only nitpick with this answer is that the way the examples are written, it should be *category* and *subcategor_ies_*.

Answer (score 6):

The precise words for what you mean are: [**hyponym**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy) (to be more specific) and **hypernym** (to be less specific).

The typical example is: *horse* is a hyponym of *animal*.

About your language example, I would say that *Italian* (as a language) is a hyponym of *European language*, which in turn is a hyponym of *language*. But the relationship between *Italian* and *verb* or *noun* is a different one. I would say that *Italian* **contains** *words* (and *words* is a hypernym of *verbs* and *nouns*).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure about the user-friendliness of these terms though..

Comment: You can say that _spoon_ is an hyponym of _cutlery_, when _cutlery_ is used to mean "knives, forks, and spoons used for eating or serving food." You cannot say _Italian_ is the hyponym of _European language_, as _Italian_ has a more restrictive meaning than _European language_. (Italian is one of the languages spoken in Europe.)

Comment: Good words, but perhaps too obscure for the desired purpose.

Comment: These words are not really that obscure. Linguists use them all the time. Any English major will know them. Heck, I got taught them in 6th grade. More to the point, these terms are certainly the most *accurate* on this page.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using the pairs *superset/subset* or *branches/leaves*.

Answer (score 2):

What about hierarchies?

In [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) terminology one can have multiple overlapping [hierarchies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube#Hierarchy) with different relationships. This is quite flexible and comfortable approach, I daresay concept

Answer (score 2):

**Instance**

Italian is an *instance* of a language.

IE and FireFox are *instances* of internet browsers.

Technical stuff follows:

There is a distinction between subset and member (or instance) but sometimes they overlap. For a set (a collection of things) one can have a subset (a subcollection). A given set can have many members -inside- it. A subset is of the same kind as the superset. A member can be any kind. A subset of size exactly 1 is usually thought of as a member or instance (because it sounds weird informally to call a subset of size 1 'a subset', i.e. "Italian is a subset of Romance languages", though technically correct sounds goofy when you think of Italian as a single language (linguistically one can think of Italian as the set of only partially mutually intelligible dialects spoken by people on the Italian peninsula).

So if you start with the set of all languages, you can then have the subset of European languages, and a subset of that the Romance languages and then the subset (or better, the instance) Italian.

The subset relation forms a hierarchy (formally a partial order) described by 'is-a'. A circle is an ellipse is a curve.

A hypernym is the word for the concept that is a parent/ancestor/predecessor/superset/superclass of the hyponym.

A hyponym is the word for the concept that is a child/descendant/successor/subset/subclass of the hyponym.

As to member, because membership is not usually thought of as a transitive relation, it doesn't really have all these successor/predecessor terms.